# Transliterate a unix file in a way that it cab be used inside IN clause of SQL

Tags: linux, unix

I have a file in unix which has below content

```
122
456
857
157
```

I want to change the above file like below

```
'122', 
' 456', 
'857', 
' 157'
```

so that i can use above output into  A sql queries.

pls provide me a sed command or tr command which can do the trick here

Comment: Are you sure about the spaces inside single quotes?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0):

Put `'` at the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of line, replace end of line with `,`, insert space to every other line starting from line 2. The `~` syntax in addresses is an extension, so it might be missing in some versions of sed.

```
sed "s/^\|$/'/g;"'$!s/$/,/;'"2~2s/'/' /"
```

Double quotes used to quote the single quotes, single quotes used to quote the `$!`.

Comment: no spaces are not needed..
if it is any line '122',
if it is last line '157'

i have managed to get the above output by while loop... but it ia damn slow